# Uibutton with title aligned to left and image aligned to right

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having an issue while i try to create a UIButton with the following options: title aligned to left and image aligned on right,

I want to do it programatically, here is what i tryed so far, it works but not like i want to

```
UIButton *definition_title = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
              definition_title.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, accordion.frame.size.width, 70.0f);
              [definition_title setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              definition_title.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
              definition_title.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
              [definition_title setTitle:@"Scan the Barcode" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              definition_title.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
              definition_title.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, accordion.frame.size.width-50, 0.0f, 0.0f);
              definition_title.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

the code above returns i Uibutton like this

```
    ________________
   |    text   image|
```

but i want it like this

```
    ________________
   |text       image|
```

Comment: I think that is because your title label is center aligned, add this line definition_title.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:**

Add a title and a image to button and adjust the title and image insets to make the text and image appear on the sides of button

[image]

**Approach 2:**

Create a subclass of UIButton and override `func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect` and `func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect` and provide the CGRect for title and image.

Example :

```
import UIKit

class MyTestButton: UIButton {

    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: self.frame.maxX - contentRect.height/*specify your button width here am using height */, y: 0, width: contentRect.height/*specify your button width here am using height */, height: contentRect.height)
    }

    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.bounds.size.width - self.imageRect(forContentRect:contentRect).width,height: contentRect.height)
    }
}
```

**O/P:**

[image]

Comment: i need the exact oposite version of this

Comment: @bonta-alexandru : Common buddy :) You can swipe the frames :)

Comment: that's great, but i dont want to subclass UIButton, and i need to write in Obj-C, also i need to do it programatically

Comment: @bonta-alexandru : You can always convert swift code to Objective C. Subclassing is also programmatically only